# How can I use colors in my console app (C)?

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I am running C in `Code:Blocks` IDE with the compiler `GNU GCC`. And I want to use colorful string output in my console application. The OS I am on is Windows

Previously, I used Borland C. So, using `textcolor()` `textbackground()` and `cprintf()` were fine. But these function does not seem to work on Code:Blocks IDE with GNU GCC Compiler wrapped with it.

What should I do to print colored texts now?

Comment: Colored output on the terminal is somewhat platform-specific. Which platform do you want this code to run on?

Comment: See this answer to a previous question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067037/139746

Comment: @PascalCuoq . It didn't help me either

Comment: You could try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9130/Add-Color-to-Console-Projects (or any of the other fistfull of articles on the same topic there) - A healthy dose of Google First, ask questions later wouldn't be to your detriment, either.

Comment: @JameySharp : The platform is windows.

Comment: @cipher - try my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193815/clock-in-c-time-light-up/13195021#13195021

Comment: @Mike Yeah! It works. Thanks for the help. So, Answer the question? And please make it clear on how to mix-up colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color in a terminal is built into standard Windows, and it's pretty easy.  You want the `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` function, here's a very quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");  // Print white text on black output
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
    printf("Hello Again!\n");  // Print Red text on black output
    getchar(); // Pause the program to admire the colors
}
```

For further highlighting you can also change the back ground, you can OR (`|`) together flags to get different colors and different back/fore grounds.

So if you wanted to do red text on a green back ground (for some reason) you could do:

```
FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN
```

[image]

You can also mix colors by OR'ing more than one foreground or background color for example:

```
FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE
```

Will give you a blue-green colored text.

Comment: One More thing. Can we also change the whole background color? how?

Comment: hmm... I'm sure there _is_ ... haven't done that before. I'll see if I can figure it out and update